# C#: почему поток не закрывается?

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Добрый день.

Есть СМТП-виндовс сервис, который слушает 25ый порт на сервере.
Я исследую его на утечки памяти, и вот что обнаружил - **клиентский поток не закрывается вообще.**

Код ниже:

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Запуск сервиса
  /// </summary>
        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            EventLog.WriteEntry( "[ " + DateTime.Now.ToString() +  "] Сервис запущен: " + ServiceName);
            WriteLog("Сервис запущен: " + ServiceName);

            try
            {
                new Thread(() =>
                {
                    Listen();
                    WriteLog(">>Listen thread is finished! <<<");
                }).Start();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                EventLog.WriteEntry( ServiceName + " error: \n" + ex.ToString());
            }        
        }

/// <summary>
/// Основной цикл сервиса - подключение клиента и работа с ним
/// </summary>
/// <param name="temp"></param>
public void Listen(object temp = null)
{
    LogHelper _logHelper = new LogHelper();                    

    try
    {
        WriteLog("***************START*******************");
        WriteLog("SMTP server started " + DateTime.Now.ToString());

        SMTP_Listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25);
        SMTP_Listener.Start();

        while (true)
        {
           // Этот Клиентский поток не закрывается !!!!
            new Thread(() =>
            {
                testA();
                WriteLog(">> Client thread is finished! <<<");
            }).Start();

        }
    }
    catch (ThreadInterruptedException e)
    {
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

//содержимое клиентского потока:

```
  void testA()
        {
            int[] arr = new int[999999999];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                arr[i] = 99999999;
            }
            WriteLog(">> array is filled <<<");
        }
```

> Я всего-лишь в потоке заполняю массив, и после того как он заполнится,
>   поток должен записать в файл 'array is filled', после чего должна
>   записаться запись в файл ">> Client thread is finished! <<<", но поток
>   не закрывается и память (по диспетчеру) не освобождается.

**Что я делаю неправильно? Подскажите пожалуйста, почему поток не закрывается?**

Спасибо

**UPD**
Оказывается, если в потоке закоментировать цикл:

```
/*int[] arr = new int[999999999];
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
                {
                    arr[i] = 99999999;
                }
*/
```

то поток закрывается, т.к. в логи пишется ">> array is filled <<<" и " Client thread is finished! <<<"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`while (true) new Thread(...).Start();` - бесконечно запускаешь потоки.

---

Потому что чтобы 1 поток даже из 2000 (а их там больше может быть) потоков досчитал до миллиарда, надо более 5 часов. И это я ещё время на переключение между потоками не учёл. Можно это на что-то ещё умножить. В общем, запусти на недельку, если ни один поток не завершится, можно будет подумать.

А ещё не факт, что там создаётся массив нужного размера - может и памяти не хватить.

Comment: В этом коде я жду клиентские подключения

Comment: Т.е. цикл должен быть. Значит ли это что запускаемые потоки никогда не будут завершаться?

Comment: @LeonardBertone, вы спросили ПОЧЕМУ, вам ответили почему

Comment: Не согласен, комент не в тему -  если я бесконечно запускаю потоки, то какое это имеет отношение к тому, что потоки не закрываются? (или я тупой, тоже возможно, и если так, то простите)

Comment: @LeonardBertone: Вы в цикле запускаете бесконечно много потоков без паузы. Код `new Thread(...).Start()` не дожидается окончания потока, только запускает его. В итоге у системы не хватает ресурсов, и, думаю, программа падает.

Comment: @LeonardBertone, потому что чтобы 1 поток даже из 2000 (а их там больше может быть) потоков досчитали до миллиарда, надо более 5 часов. И это я ещё время на переключение между потоками не учёл. Можно это на что-то ещё умножить. В общем, запусти на недельку, если ни один поток не завершится, можно будет подумать.

Comment: @VladD, при том try-catch, вероятно, не падает.

Comment: @LeonardBertone, а ещё, ты уверен, что массив нужного размера выделяется вообще?

Comment: @Qwertiy: И поскольку Exception глотается, то об этом никто и не узнает.